# How define a font for all a flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter

I would like to know how I can define a font for an entire mobile app. I have read something about themedata. I have defined themedata in materialapp with the font on main.dart but the font is used only on main.dart and not on all mobile app pages. Do you know how do it?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'YourFontFamilyName',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i use materialapp on all mobile dart file i use, is it normal ??? Now i use materialapp on main.dart and define the theme as you have shown but the font works only on main.dart

Comment: @axis-medias You don't need to use `MaterialApp` on all files. Use `Scaffold` instead

Comment: i accept your answer thanks :) I have deleted all materialapp and now it works the font is on all my mobile page

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you already have it defined in your `theme data` and it's not working. Try the method below: It works perfectly:

You can extend the default `text theme` and apply a `font-family` to all of their instances. To do this, check the code below, works perfectly:

Add the code snippet in the `themedata` constructor.

```
textTheme: baseTheme.textTheme.apply(
      // add your desired font family here
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    ),
```

I hope this hepls.